# fopen returns false on subdirecory

Tags: php, android, apache, centos

Hi I am trying to upload an image file to my server from my android application. It seems that  I cannot upload any file to my server rather than a specific directory(pics). If I try to upload into a subdirectory of pics then fopen returns false. 
here is my php file

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$picname=$_REQUEST['picname'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

//$shapicname = SHA1($picname);

$dir1 = 'pics/'.substr($picname,0,2);
$dir2 = substr($picname,2,2);

$targetfilename1 = $dir1;
$targetfilename2 =  $dir2;

if (!file_exists($dir1)) {
    mkdir($dir1); //create the directory
    chmod($targetfilename1, 0777); //make it writable
}

//chdir($dir1);

$file = fopen('/var/www/html/'.$dir1.'/'.$picname, 'wb');


if (!$file) {
   echo "false ".$dir1.$picname;
}
else {
   $fwrite = fwrite($file,$binary);

   fclose($file);

   echo "uploaded".$fwrite.$file;
}
?>
```

pics folder is owned by apache user and has 0777 permissions

Any ideas?

I am posting php error log

[Thu Aug 02 18:32:34 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.Xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  fopen(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid/gid is 0/0 is not allowed to access /var/www/html/pics/53 owned by uid/gid 48/48 in /var/www/html/uploadshaimage.php on line 23
[Thu Aug 02 18:32:34 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.Xxx.xx] PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/html/pics/53/5344.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/uploadshaimage.php on line 23

Comment: You also have to check that `$dir1` actually is a dir  - it could potentially be a normal file with the same name. And also have to check `is_writeable()` as well.

Comment: Are there any errors? Check the error log.

Comment: It actually creates $dir1 if it does not exists and gives the appropriate permissions to it , as for is_writeable() you mean the file?

Comment: if fopen is returning false, you should be getting a warning (either in logs or on screen depending on the setting of `display_errors`).  What's the warning saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found 2 solutions working

A. Turn safe_mode off on php.ini (a bit risky!)

B. give the permissions of pics directory recursively to the subdirectories(gid was the problem!)

Thanks to everybody for the help

Answer (score 1):

1. Folder permission
2. PHP.ini settings - allow url open or file functions arent enabled.
3. Wrong Path - verify if the file or the path is correct or does exist.

Comment: file_exists,function_exists,is_writable

Comment: 1.folder permission is set to 777
2.allow_url_open is on , file_functions not found on php.ini
3.Path is checked!

Answer (score 0):

You know, I can't help but wonder, are you sure that the path really is `'/var/www/html/'.$dir1.'/'.$picname`? You're using a relative path for `$dir1`, but an absolute path in `fopen`. What happens if you set `$dir1` to the absolute path from the beginning?

---

FWIW, you also have the wrong Content-Type for what you are outputting.